# Can there be a malicious XSS attack inside the members section of my site?

Tags: xss

Let's say on my site, after you login you're in the members only section and I'll pull some data from the database that you put in there previously and display it on the page. Can there be a malicious injection of js code that you previously entered if only you can see it?

So on my site you can put

```
<script>alert('hi')</script>
```

into your address for example and on the page that shows your address, this will indeed run, but it's something you put in and only you can see it.

So I'm trying to decide how concerned I should be about this, but I can't imagine what a user could put into their own data which only appears to them if they wanted to harm another user.

Comment: I definitely can, but I'm just curious as to what's the worst that could happen if I don't. How vigilant do I need to be in validating input from users that only they can see again?

Comment: The worst that could happen is that someone could hijack a session and access sensetive data accessible over the user accounts & tons of other stuff but is it really worth investing much time in writing that kind of secure code? i doubt it :) consider using a framework like codeigniter that does a lot of filtering by default

Comment: @Kaleun - how can I hijack your session by injecting js code into my page that's on the same domain? If you never see it, you never run it, so what's the harm?

Comment: In this case you need to protect against CSRF, so a user cannot trick a user into modifying his/her data and thus indirectly XSSing him/herself.
Also self-XSS through clickjacking or similar could be a problem.

Comment: The possibilities are endless :) Security is always a tradeoff. I never needed "that much" security, altough i run a dating website with several hundred users.

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to protect against CSRF in order to make sure that one user does not XSS another through CSRF from a different site
2. Being tricked into self-XSS is still a problem. Here is an example: http://www.exploit-db.com/download_pdf/17017/